# How to use ISO8859-9 encoding in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, encoding, character-encoding

I maked a file containing "ırmak" with a text editor via encoding ISO8859-9.
Then, I tried to print the content with "cat" command in the terminal. But I could not.
I use the commands

```
 export LC_ALL=tr_TR.ISO8859-9
 export LANG=tr_TR.ISO8859-9
 cat    text.txt
```

After these commands the terminal printed:

```
 �rmak
```

**Note**: The for the command

```
 echo ırmak
```

the terminal prints:

```
 ırmak
```

Comment: Welcome to SU @user :) I'm curious, what does say `file myfile` and what's the output of `locale` ?

Comment: I do not know the meaning of the keyword `locale`. Could you explain?

Comment: (1) "What's the output of `locale`" means "type `locale` in your shell, hit Enter and tell us what you got". After your `export LC_ALL=…` and `export LANG=…` there should be no surprises, so please check also `locale -a` to make sure `tr_TR.ISO8859-9` is among locales available (generated) in your system. (2) When you run `echo ırmak` normally in a console, is the non-ASCII letter printed right? This test is to make sure the font you're using contains a proper glyph for the letter.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski I wasn't enough clear, and the OP reply by editing the question and we can see there's a unapropriate font in use or still bad locales confs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The echo command works because there is no encoding problem when I only use terminal. The problem is that I cannot set encoding of the terminal so that It reads my files correctly.

Comment: Hello @user The `echo` command works because your locales are good and you have an appropriate font... However, run the command `locale -a` so we can be sure this part of the diagnose is fine. I suspect that the file has another encoding...